# Call before_update if an attribute is filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the way to call the before_update trigger only if a particular attribute is filled?

Here is a part of my code:

```
before_update { self.gravatar = gravatar.downcase }

validates :gravatar, :on => :update, length: { maximum: 128 },
                    format: { with: VALID_GRAVATAR_REGEX }, 
                    allow_blank: true
```

Indeed I want to call the downcase function on the attribute only if this one is filled in the edit form.

I currently have this following error:

> undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

Which is logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like that ?
`before_update { self.gravatar = gravatar.downcase if gravatar.present? }`

Answer (score 3):

Rails callbacks accept the [`:if` and `:unless` options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html).

```
class Model
  before_update :normalize_gravatar, if: :gravatar?

  protected

  def normalize_gravatar
    self.gravatar = gravatar.downcase
  end
end
```

The code above is a shortcut for

```
class Model
  before_update :normalize_gravatar, if: ->() { gravatar.present? }

  protected

  def normalize_gravatar
    self.gravatar = gravatar.downcase
  end
end
```

In your case, it's probably easier to always run the callback and make sure it doesn't crash if the attribute is empty.

```
class Model
  before_update :normalize_gravatar

  protected

  def normalize_gravatar
    self.gravatar = gravatar.downcase if gravatar.present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
before_update { self.gravatar = gravatar.downcase}, if: ->(s) { s.gravatar.present? }
```